# Por qué java dice que una variable podría no estar inicializada si no es cierto

Tags: java, variables

En este código, el usuario puede introducir por teclado strings o enteros hasta que introduzca la cadena "fin". En ese momento, el programa debe decir cuál ha sido el mayor entero introducido y el menor entero introducido.

El problema es que hago un condicional para que detecte el primer número introducido (if (primero == true){...) y en ese momento se inicializan las variables mayor y menor con la cantidad de ese primer número. Pero al introducir el segundo número en el programa, me salta un error diciendo que las variables mayor o menor podrían no estar inicializadas. Lo hace porque entra en el else del condicional anterior, pero es imposible que entre en ese else sin haber pasado antes por el if y por tanto es imposible que esas variables no estén inicializadas en el punto en el que salta el error.
¿Por qué java dice que la variable podría no estar inicializada si cuando llegue a ese punto ya tiene que estar inicializada forzosamente? ¿Qué solución tiene esto?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Prueba5 {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        String cadena=" ";
        boolean primero=true;
        boolean numero = true;
        int mayor;
        int menor;
        boolean algunnumero = false;
        while(cadena.equals("fin")==false){
            System.out.println("Introduce una cadena o número:");
            Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
            cadena = entrada.nextLine();
            char x =cadena.charAt(0);
            if (x=='-' || x=='0' || x=='1' || x=='2' || x=='3' || x=='4' || x=='5' || x=='6' || x=='7' || x=='8' || x=='9'){
            numero=true;
            }
            else{numero=false;}
            if(numero==false){
            }
            if (cadena.length()>1){
                for (int i=1;i<=(cadena.length()-1);i++){
                    x = cadena.charAt(i);
                    if (x=='0' || x=='1' || x=='2' || x=='3' || x=='4' || x=='5' || x=='6' || x=='7' || x=='8' || x=='9'){
                    }
                    else{numero=false;}
            }
            }   

            if (numero==true){
                algunnumero=true;
            }
            
            if (numero==true){
                int cantidad = Integer.parseInt(cadena);
                if (primero==true){
                    primero=false;
                    mayor = cantidad;
                    menor = cantidad;
                }
                else{
                    if (cantidad>mayor){
                        mayor=cantidad;
                    }
                    if (cantidad<menor){
                            menor=cantidad;
                    }
                }
            }    
            }
        if (algunnumero==true){
            System.out.println("El número mayor es "+mayor);
            System.out.println("El número menor es "+menor);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("No has introducido ningún número.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que se está produciendo es un error en tiempo de compilación. Esto se debe a que **Java tiene la regla de inicializar las variables locales antes de accederlas o usarlas y esto se comprueba en tiempo de compilación**. Si el compilador cree que una variable local podría no haberse inicializado antes de la siguiente instrucción que la está utilizando, obtendrá este error. No obtendras este error si solo declaras la variable local pero no la usas.

Esto sucederá aunque estes 100% seguro de que se va a pasar por el if ergo le colocaras algún valor. Es diferente si en vez de hacerlo con variables locales lo haces con variables de instancia, variables propias de las clases que no son declaradas dentro de métodos. Podes verlo con un ejemplo simple de una clase:

```
public class MyClass {
  private int myvariable; // variable de instancia sin inicializar
  MyClass(){ // constructor
  }
  public int getVariable(){ // metodo que retorna la variable sin inicializar
    return this.myvariable; 
  }
}
```

En la clase Main:

```
MyClass miclase = new MyClass();
System.out.println(miclase.getVariable()); // obtengo 0 y no un error, ya que las variables de instancia son automáticamente inicializadas con valores por defecto si no las inicializamos nosotros mismos.
```

Como mayor y menor son variables locales y no de instancia, esto no aplicara, necesitaras no solo declarar sino declarar e inicializar a la vez (yo decidí ponerles valor 0 por defecto):

```
int mayor = 0;
int menor = 0;
```

Ahí ya no deberías tener errores de compilación. Tenes más información en este [Articulo](https://www.java67.com/2016/07/how-to-fix-variable-might-not-have-been-initialized-error-in-java.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias. No te puedo puntuar porque no tengo reputación suficiente. Gracias a tu respuesta lo he arreglado con el código con el que me voy a auto responder (no lo pego aquí porque no me deja hacer comentarios tan largos).

Comment: @Ruben no podes votar, pero podes marcarla como aceptada usando el tilde. Saludos.